# Running a command based on a file in the directory

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, rhel, appearance

I have some scripts setup that I would like a master script to call based on a files appearance in a directory. Basically I have what's show below.

Script A   uses file a

Script B   uses file b

Command C  uses file c

I would like to have a master script that looks for file a and if it's there run Script A if not there skip it then proceeds through B and C. All of the files and scripts are to be located within the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a shell script `a.sh` if file `a.file` exists and is a regular file, you can use this construct:

```
[ -f a.file ] && source a.sh
```